# change value by reference in ruby

Tags: ruby

I implemeting async thread manager and I want to pass reference to thread, where it should save the results of his work. And then when all thread finished i will handle all results.

What I need is to know how to work with 'references'.

lets assume I have variable `result` (or `hash[:result1]`), I want to pass it to the thread like

```
def test_func
 return 777;
end

def thread_start(result)
 Thread.new do
  result = test_func;
 end
end
```

and I want is to get following result

```
result = 555
thread_start(result);
#thread_wait_logic_there
result == 777; #=> true

hash = {:res1 => 555};
thread_start(hash[:res1])
#thread_wait_logic_there
hash[:res1]==777 #=> true
```

what should I chnage in my code to make it work?

Ruby version is 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass entrire hash to function:

```
def test_func
  return 777;
end

def thread_start(hash, key)
  Thread.new do
    hash[key] = test_func;
  end
end
```

Then this will work:

```
hash = {:res1 => 555};
thread_start(hash, :res1)
hash[:res1]==777 #=> true
```

Also if you want to be sure that you getting result after computations finished you must wait for thread, like this:

```
hash = {:res1 => 555};
thread_start(hash, :res1).join
hash[:res1]==777 #=> true
```

Edit: Added key,join

Comment: the problem that I don't know the key to set value inside my realworld example. And it will be multiple threads working with results. So each of them will need to have their own key. So that's dosen't work.

Comment: @valodzka you are absolutely right. Using join yields the expected result.